# Interface with generic type used as generic type within second interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface that references accepts generic type:

```
public interface IEntity<TType>
```

I hope to pass a reference of this to a second interface that takes a generic type:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : IEntity, new()
```

I have tried getting this to work but have so far failed to have it build.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: What exactly did fail? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interface is `IEntity<T>`, not `IEntity`. This means that the signature of your `IRepository` needs to reflect this:

```
public interface IEntity<TType>

public interface IRepository<T, TEntity> : IDisposable where T : IEntity<TEntity>, new()
```